# Windows Template Studio - Customizing the Navigation Pane

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-template-studio

I am trying to customize the style of my Navigation Pane but I have found difficult to access the UI elements related to it. Basically, I would want to have the top part of the navigation pane as a certain color, which would be a continuation of our header. This is what I have now :

[image]

I would need to be able to change the color of the back button and hamburgermenu button areas but I can't seem to be able to access these elements like the rest of the navigationViewItems.

How can I achieve this? I am using the Navigation Pane project type with the Code Behind design pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the NavigationView's template to achieve your target. Go to the **'Document Outline -> right click your navigation view control -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy'**.

For example, if you want to change the color of the back button, it should be in the 'NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle' like this:

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        ....
 </Style>
```

You could change its background, foreground etc.